# path as variable

Tags: unix, bash, command-line-interface, path

```
BACKUP_SERVER_NAME="name"
BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME="user"
COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS="/cygdrive/c/unix_test_copy"

scp -r /$1/ $PRIMARY_SERVER_USERNAME@$PRIMARY_SERVER_NAME:$COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS
```

How can I pass a path to variable and how I can pass it to the command and execute it?

This is my bash file, if any one can convert it:

```
PRIMARY_SERVER_NAME="error.com.jo"

PRIMARY_SERVER_USERNAME="Administrator"

BACKUP_SERVER_NAME="V1DEV1.com.jo"

BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME="Administrator"

COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS="/cygdrive/c/unix_test_copy"

SCAN_BATCH_FILE_WINDOWS="c:\\scan.bat"

LOG_FILE="/var/log/scan.log"

if [ -f "$1" ]

then

scp -r $1 ${BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME}@${BACKUP_SERVER_NAME}:${COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS}"

server_status=$?

server_status_on=0

if [$server_status -eq $server_status_on ];

then

ssh -l ${BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME}@${PRIMARY_SERVER_NAME} 'cmd /c ${SCAN_BATCH_FILE_WINDOWS} {$COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS}\'$1'
else

scp -r $1 ${BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME}@${BACKUP_SERVER_NAME}:${COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS}

ssh -l ${BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME} ${BACKUP_SERVER_NAME} 'cmd /c ${SCAN_BATCH_FILE_WINDOWS}${COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS}\'$1''

fi

error_code=$?"

echo "[$(date +%c)] $1 error_code = $?" >> ${LOG_FILE}

exit $error_code"

else

echo "[$(date +%c)] $1 error_code = 5" >> ${LOG_FILE}

exit 5

fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create backup_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
BACKUP_SERVER_NAME="name"
BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME="user"
COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS="/cygdrive/c/unix_test_copy"

scp -r $1 ${BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME}@${BACKUP_SERVER_NAME}:${COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS}
```

make executable:

```
chmod +x backup_script.sh
```

run:

```
backup_script.sh /etc/
```

To debug, change

`scp -r $1 ${BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME}@${BACKUP_SERVER_NAME}:${COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS}`

to

`echo "scp -r $1 ${BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME}@${BACKUP_SERVER_NAME}:${COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS}"`

or run:

`set -x`

Comment: it is dosen't work the following error appear :- `ssh: name: host/servname not known`

Comment: the following result appear :- `scp -r hi.txt @:`